# centre vs. center among Americans

Tags: american-english

I have seen Americans use centre.

Yet I have never seen an American write "centre of the circle". So far I've only seen them write it for places (buildings or areas) where the place carries weight.

Are there any rules as to when which should be used among Americans?

(I saw this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/center-or-centre-in-sports-vocabulary) but it doesn't help since it's under the assumption that it's just a matter of Britain vs American)

Comment: My impression is that it's similar to the use of ["theatre" vs. "theater" in American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202651/theater-vs-theatre-in-american-english)

Comment: Americans do not use normally *centre*. But you can name a building or place whatever you like, and plenty of developers think unusual, vaguely archaic or foreign spellings will add some flair, hence the chronic infection of *Shoppes*, *Centres*, *Olde Townes*, *Pointes*, and so forth. And let me tell you: The Olde Tyme Smoak Shoppe in Centre Pointe at Olde Towne is not of the caliber of the old-time smoke shop near the center point of old town, plus it's on the far side of the watre.

Comment: That hurt just to read as a comment. And the guilty are largely incapable of stringing together a proper sentence in the first place.

Comment: Hmm... If the place is old enough, it may have been named before AmE switched from *centre* to *center*. Care to give any examples?

Comment: @choster Don't you want to edit that to have _Ye Olde_, with incorrect article for lack of a thorn (þ)?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus No, we don't want to run into the [*ye* tax](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1986-04-20/features/8601280626_1_potato-skins-tax-shelter-restaurants). Such is commercial real estate's insatiable demand for *e*'s that hundreds of tech startups have been priced out the market, hence Flickr, Pixlr, Tumblr, Scribd, et al.

Comment: Yeah, near here we have some (as I pronounce them) *Shoppies on Mainey*.  And I wouldn't be surprised if one of the Shoppies calls itself a *Sentry*.

Comment: @choster Ah, that explains why the company ZZZZ Best was a notorious swindle.

Comment: Where have you seen Americans use *centre*?

Comment: @aparente001- Google "Centre Pointe Apartments".

Comment: I'd think the comment above with all the upvotes would make a good answer...

Comment: On the one hand, *centre/center* or *theatre/theater* seem like simple questions of choice and it's obvious to all of us that Britain went one way and US America, the other.

However, if we look at words like *central* or *theatrical* does it not become obvious that someone in US America must have put rather more effort into that choice than is immediately apparent?

Comment: @Laurel: *Newton Centre* (a neighborhood) and *Centre Street* in Newton, MA, were named before the modern spelling (and for a while, our GPS was calling it Sahntre Street, as if we were in Quebec).

Comment: The answer to the question (like the answer to most "what are the rules questions, here) is that there is no rule. *Most* AmE speakers and writers use what *most* other AmE speakers and writers use, *most* of the time - and that happens to be *center*. That's all.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Alternation between "er" in base forms and "r" in derived forms existed already in Latin for many words, and has passed from Latin into modern British English as well as American English. On both sides of the Atlantic we have "integer" vs. "integral"; "metric" vs. "pentameter"; "arbiter" vs. "arbitration"; "minister" vs. "(ad)ministration".

Comment: @Sumelic I don’t understand that. Are you talking about *er* v *re* or what, please?
Either way what difference would a common Latin base make to modern US American v British usage?
How are *integer* and *integral* comparable, please? Even if you’re suggesting they should be *integre* or *integeral* I think you’re either skipping over a level, or adding something with no place in life.
More, how could *metric* be compared to *pentameter*?
Are you asking for *arbitre* or *arbiteration*? *Ministre* or *(ad)ministeration* or what, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: "integer" and "integral" have the same root, and are used as corresponding terms in certain contexts. Likewise, "metric" can be used to refer to aspects of poetry, e.g. we speak of the "metrical" pattern of a line, despite the fact that the related poetry term "pentameter" uses the spelling "meter". I'm not asking for anything; just noting that the discrepancy you brought up between the spellings of "center" and "central" exists for many other pairs of related words.

Comment: Yes "integer" and "integral" have the same root, and I’ve never noticed them corresponding. D’you have an example? 

To me comparing metric/metrical and pentameter doesn’t work for exactly the same reason: *er* is not *re*.

In all those cases there does seem to be mechanical difficulty in moving from, eg, *center* to *central* and clearly that exists for many other pairs of related words.

Is there a fourth choice or must we ignore it, state that this tends to indicate *re* is correct and *er* is not, or recognise that spelling doesn’t dictate meaning, and doubly nt in English?

Comment: Americans only use "centre" while holding a teacup with the little finger extended.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Are you claiming "metric" and "meter" are not related?  It's hard to understand your argument here.

Comment: No, Casey. What led you to think that?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The fact you ignored his point, didn't reply to it, and continued to pretend that center and central don't correspond in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Ily  It's so long ago but if you meant Casey's point thanks, I gave it due respect. For clarification now, no; of course I'm not!

If you meant Herrison's point I'm sorry I helped spend all that effort on all that detail for such a simple subject.

In every case I recall where British and US American English differ, whether simple spelling as here and …our/…or, …ize/…ise, tyre/tire, or real differences like bonnet/hood, boot/trunk or faucet/tap it seems both were common in Britain before the settlers migrated, and what became US usage was more common.

What more is  needful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any rules as to when which should be used among Americans?

In American English, after the spelling reforms of Webster, *center* is not spelled *centre*.

Names are capitalized proper nouns and are free to be spelled in any way.

eg: The Town Centre Mall is the mall in the center of town.

Comment: Already checked but -1 for not noting that the use is specifically archaic or a specific attempt to class up the joint.

Answer (score -3):

Those who use "centre" in everyday writing are usually from abroad or write for The New Yorker.

Comment: Is there we have a discussion about, relative to the US, whether Canada is *abroad* or not?

Comment: The New Yorker (notoriously) has a style guide; they don't just let people write "centre" or "center" based on personal preferences. I can't find any evidence that the current New Yorker style guide calls for "centre" to be used in more circumstances than is usual for an American publication (basically, all the results for "centre" that I found from an online search of their site are in  proper nouns, aside from a few examples from the 1940s).

Comment: Side point: The comment above tacking a "citation needed" on the _New Yorker_ slam is hilarious. It's very obviously intended towards the kind of people who pretend to _read_ the _New Yorker_ and is precisely on point. That half-assed gesture towards class is _precisely_ the origin of any American use of the spelling 'centre'.